# Change window Exposé behavior outside of Interface Builder

Tags: objective-c, cocoa

Here's the setting I'm talking about:

[image]

I'm wondering if I can change the Exposé behavior on the fly, or even during initialization in my code? I have some users that don't wish to see my app firmly planted on the desktop (Stationary Behavior), so I wanted to add an option to allow it to roam freely during Exposé.  However, I haven't found a property to change this on my window.  Is it possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you can use this NSWindow method:

```
- (void)setCollectionBehavior:(NSWindowCollectionBehavior)behavior
```

[List of NSWindowCollectionBehavior options.](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ApplicationKit/Classes/NSWindow_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/c_ref/NSWindowCollectionBehavior)

Comment: Ah that's right.  I had figured that out before but somehow it slipped my mind.  Thanks, I'll accept it as soon as it's available.